# How to build a multidimensional array or dictionary from a list of paths

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm new to Swift and I'm attacking what it seems to a big challenge for a novice.

Basically, I want to create a multidimensional array based on a list of file paths.

Let's assume I have this list:

```
/Users/gab/Desktop/folder/file1.jpg
/Users/gab/Desktop/folder/file2.jpg
/Users/gab/Desktop/folder/subfolder/
/Users/gab/Desktop/my_file.txt
```

I want to create an array that looks like this:

```
["Users":
    ["gab":
        ["Desktop":
            ["folder":
                ["subfolder":[]],
                "file1.jpg",
                "file2.jpg"
            ],
            "my_file.txt"
        ]
    ]
]
```

Now I know this might be a bad idea to create an AnyObject dictionary and mix Strings and Dictionary types, I'm totally open to using the best practice here but I wanted to keep the question simple.

As mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33855993/1405122, I believe it's best to create an array of struct, but my question is still how do I recursively fill the array/dictionary ?

I'm way more familiar with PHP, and basically what I'm trying to do is to port this post's answer to Swift: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4903871 (the fisrt part)

For the moment I'm using the File Manager enumerator to iterate through the file system:

```
var files = [String: FileSystemObject]()

let fsTree = fm.enumerator(atPath: path)!
while let fsNode = fsTree.nextObject() as? NSString {
    // get each folders by seperating the path
    let parts = fsNode.components(separatedBy: "/")

    // here i'm having trouble figuring how to do it
    for n in 0...parts.count(){
        // fill files
    }
}
```

In the PHP example, the user is passing the same initial array by reference. Here in Swift I don't know if that would be the solution, if even it is possible.

Thanks :)

**Edit:**

Ok, so I figured something using a [tree](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1053-swift-algorithm-club-swift-tree-data-structure#toc-anchor-001), as suggested by @MartinR.
It works, only I don't know if this is the best practice or if there is a more fancy, or a more "swifty" way of doing this. But it works...

1. Created a "node" tree to hold folders and files infos:

   ```
   class Node {
       var path: String
       var children: [Node] = []
       weak var parent: Node?

       init(path: String) {
           self.path = path
       }

       func add(child: Node) {
           children.append(child)
           child.parent = self
       }

       func search(path: String) -> Node? {
           if path == self.path {
               return self
           }
           for child in children {
               if let found = child.search(path: path) {
                   return found
               }
           }
           return nil
       }
   }
   ```
2. in the enumerator loop:

   ```
   // split the path folders in an array
   let parts = fsNode.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.init(charactersIn: "/")).components(separatedBy: "/")

   // this node ID will be used to find the parent node in the tree
   var nodeID = "/"

   // build a node ID (represented by a path) by traversing the path from its root
   for p in parts{
       nodeID = nodeID + (nodeID == "/" ? "" : "/") + p

       // check if a node exists for this path, so we're not adding the same folder twice.
       // file search will always be nil
       if root.search(path: nodeID) == nil {
           let parent = root.search(path: (nodeID as NSString).deletingLastPathComponent)
           // create a node for the file or folder
           let node = Node(path: nodeID)
           // add the node to the parent node in the tree
           parent?.add(child: node)
       }
   }
   ```

**Edit 2:**
Definitely not the best way to do it. With a large number of files, it just takes forever.

Comment: A *tree* might be a better data structure to represent a file system hierarchy, see for example https://www.raywenderlich.com/1053-swift-algorithm-club-swift-tree-data-structure.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR, will check this out :) Seems like the right thing to use, I didn't know about trees. Still I will need to fill it recursively. Thanks again

Comment: @MartinR don't you mean a trie?

Comment: @gabriel Do you actually need to have this data structure in memory? In every case when I've had to work with the filesystem, I was able to achieve everything I needed by just relying on the file system, rather than trying to duplicate subtrees of it in my own app.